# O método getSelectionStart(TextView) retorna valor incorreto

Tags: android, textview

Preciso recuperar uma string selecionada pelo usuário em um TextView, porém o método [getSelectionStart](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getSelectionStart()) retorna o mesmo valor da getSelectionEnd.

Segue um exemplo na imagem abaixo:

[image: getSelectionStart]

Efetuei o teste em um Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge e em um Asus e ambos apresentaram o mesmo comportamento.

Alguém sabe alguma outra forma de recuperar uma string selecionada em um TextView?

**EDIT:**

Código de exemplo:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
int selectionStart = textView.getSelectionStart(); // Retorna 10 (era pra retornar 4)
int selectionEnd = textView.getSelectionEnd(); // Retorna 10 (correto)
```

Obrigado.

Comment: tem algum código?

Comment: @seamusd, adicionado.